# Delete empty Changelist Perforce Java API

Tags: java, api, perforce, changelist

Was just wondering if anybody knows how to remove an empty changelist from perforce through the p4java API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `deletePendingChangelist` method in the IServer class:  http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/server/IServer.html